# java program pauses at times while connecting to google spreadsheet?

Tags: java, google-sheets

My program is taking pauses in between while connecting to the google spreadsheet if i made my program to run for a long time? Can anyone provide me with the solution please......
Thanks in advance...............

```
public class Index {
    static final SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService(
            "Print Google Spreadsheet Demo");
    static URL metafeedUrl;
    static SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet;
    static URL listFeedUrl;
    static ListFeed listFeed;
    static List<String> allBitCoinAddresses = new ArrayList<String>();
    static int counter = 0;
    static int value = 0;
    static FileReader fr;
    static BufferedReader br;
    static String username;
    static String password;
    static String spreadsheet_url;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            ServiceException, URISyntaxException {

        System.out.println("program started....................");
        int reconnect = 0;
        fr = new FileReader(new File("userNpwd.txt"));
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String read;
        int i = 0;
        while ((read = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (i == 0) {
                username = read;
                i++;
            } else if (i == 1) {
                password = read;
                i++;
            } else {
                spreadsheet_url = read;
                spreadsheet_url = spreadsheet_url.replace("/edit#gid=0", "");
                spreadsheet_url = spreadsheet_url.substring(spreadsheet_url
                        .lastIndexOf('/'));
                spreadsheet_url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets"
                        + spreadsheet_url;
            }
        }
        while (reconnect == 0)
            try {

                // Login and prompt the user to pick a sheet to use.
                service.setUserCredentials(username, password);

                // Load sheet
                metafeedUrl = new URL(spreadsheet_url);
                spreadsheet = service.getEntry(metafeedUrl,
                        SpreadsheetEntry.class);
                listFeedUrl = ((WorksheetEntry) spreadsheet.getWorksheets()
                        .get(0)).getListFeedUrl();

                listFeed = service.getFeed(listFeedUrl, ListFeed.class);
                reconnect = 1;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                reconnect = 0;
            }
        while (true) {
            checkForAddressChange();
        }
    }

    private static void checkForAddressChange() throws IOException,
            ServiceException, URISyntaxException {

        ListFeed feed;

        try {
            feed = service.getFeed(listFeedUrl, ListFeed.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return;
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            return;
        }

        int i = 0;

        // ...............
        try {
            feed = service.getFeed(listFeedUrl, ListFeed.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return;
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("checking.................................");

        for (ListEntry entry : feed.getEntries()) {

            try {
                if (!entry.getCustomElements().getValue("BitCoinAddress")
                        .equals(null)
                        & !entry.getCustomElements().getValue("SpreadsheetURL")
                                .equals(null)) {
                    if (counter == 0) {
                        if (value < feed.getEntries().size()) {
                            allBitCoinAddresses.add(entry.getCustomElements()
                                    .getValue("BitCoinAddress"));
                            value += 1;
                            continue;
                        }
                        counter += 1;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (allBitCoinAddresses.get(i).equals(
                            entry.getCustomElements()
                                    .getValue("BitCoinAddress"))) {
                        i += 1;
                        continue;
                    } else {

                        System.out
                                .println("value changed...................................");
                        String url = entry.getCustomElements().getValue(
                                "SpreadsheetURL");
                        url = url.replace("/edit#gid=0", "");
                        url = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/'));
                        url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets"
                                + url;
                        System.out.println("url is : " + url);
                        Scrapping scrapping = new Scrapping(url);
                        scrapping.deleteEnteries();
                        System.out.println("url is: "
                                + entry.getCustomElements().getValue(
                                        "SpreadsheetURL"));
                        scrapping
                                .insertIntoSpreadsheet(entry
                                        .getCustomElements().getValue(
                                                "BitCoinAddress"));
                        allBitCoinAddresses.set(i, entry.getCustomElements()
                                .getValue("BitCoinAddress"));
                        System.out.println("spreadsheet updated!!!!!!!");
                        i += 1;
                        System.out.println("SIZE OF : "
                                + allBitCoinAddresses.size());

                    }
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                System.out.println("nullllllll");
                continue;
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException iobe) {

                System.out.println("exception in index out of bounds");
                allBitCoinAddresses.add(entry.getCustomElements().getValue(
                        "BitCoinAddress"));

                // change the spreadsheet.........
                String url = entry.getCustomElements().getValue(
                        "SpreadsheetURL");
                url = url.replace("/edit#gid=0", "");
                url = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/'));
                url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets"
                        + url;

                Scrapping scrapping = new Scrapping(url);
                scrapping.deleteEnteries();
                System.out.println("url is: "
                        + entry.getCustomElements().getValue("SpreadsheetURL"));
                scrapping.insertIntoSpreadsheet(entry.getCustomElements()
                        .getValue("BitCoinAddress"));

                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you connect? Please add some more context and code to your question, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: May be too frequently connections and google throttling requests ?

Comment: Reto : i'm using service.setUserCredentials(username, password); method to connect to google account.

Comment: yes  Maxim Akristiniy i am continuously checking a column of a spreadsheet for any changes. But i have made the connection only once at the start of the program and after that i am just iterating through the rows.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a thread for the connecting and reading section.
even if ,for whatever reason it takes time to your app to connect (might be network problem, slow computer or what not) the process will run in the background and thus will not pause the whole app.